# Conditional probability question: $P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid B^{\,\prime})=1$?

Tags: probability

A simple question:

If P(A|B) = 0.1

Does P(A|B') = 0.9?

Comment: No work shown. Vote to close with immediate effect.

Comment: No. However, probabilities conditional on a particular event $B$ follow the general rules of probabilities. Thus $P(A|B) = 1 - P(A^\prime|B).$

Comment: No, but the opposite is true, meaning that if $P(A|B) = p, P(\bar A | B)= 1-p$

Comment: Hint: Use Bayes' Rule and the Rule of Complements.

Comment: Who upvotes this sort of question?

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, $A$ and $B$ could be independent so that:
$$
\Pr[A \mid B] = \Pr[A] = \Pr[A \mid B']
$$

Answer (score 0):

$P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid B^{\,\prime})=1$, not always. But can we go further? Let see.

---

---

Let $P(B)<\dfrac{1}{2}$

Then,

$\begin{align}P(B)P(A\mid B)+P(B)P(A\mid B')<P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B')\\=P((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B'))=P(A)\end{align}$

$\Rightarrow P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid B^{\,\prime})<\dfrac{P(A)}{P(B)}$

Similarly if $P(B)>\dfrac{1}{2}$, then $P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid B^{\,\prime})>\dfrac{P(A)}{P(B)}$

And if $P(B)=\dfrac{1}{2}$, then $P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid B^{\,\prime})=\dfrac{P(A)}{P(B)}=2P(A)$

---

If $A$ and $B$ independent, $P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid B^{\,\prime})=P(A)+P(A)=2P(A)$